# UITableView crashing when deleting row with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        VDL()

        //sets stepper configs
        setsStepper.wraps = false
        setsStepper.autorepeat = true
        setsStepper.continuous = true
        setsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        setsStepper.minimumValue = 0
        setsStepper.maximumValue = 500
        setsStepper.value = 0

        //reps stepper configs
        repsStepper.wraps = false
        repsStepper.autorepeat = true
        repsStepper.continuous = true
        repsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        repsStepper.minimumValue = 0
        repsStepper.maximumValue = 500
        repsStepper.value = 0

        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    @IBOutlet var exerciseTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var daysPickerView: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var exerciseName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var setsStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var repsStepper: UIStepper!

    @IBOutlet var setsNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var repsNumber: UILabel!

    var daysArray = [TrainingDay]()
    var detailsArray = [TrainingDetails]()

    func VDL () {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDay")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dayIndex", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        daysArray = (moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDay])!
        if daysArray.count == 0 { // nothing there
            let dayEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
            let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
            for (index, name) in enumerate(days) {
                let newDay = TrainingDay(entity: dayEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
                newDay.day = name
                newDay.dayIndex = index
                daysArray.append(newDay)
                println("NAME: \(newDay.day) INDEX: \(newDay.dayIndex)")
            }
            var error: NSError?
            moc!.save(&error)
        }
    }


    func appendTrainingDetailsToArray () {
        let row = daysPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let currentDay = daysArray[row]

        let detailsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: detailsEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text
        trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.trainingDay = currentDay

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("CURRENT SETTING: \(trainingdetails.trainingDay)")
        }
    }

    func fetchTrainingDetails() -> NSFetchRequest {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDetails")
        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "trainingDay", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        return fetchRequest
    }


    @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        appendTrainingDetailsToArray()
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchTrainingDetails(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func setsStepperAction(sender: UIStepper) {
        println("\(Int(sender.value))")
        setsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    @IBAction func repsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
        println("\(Int(sender.value))")
        repsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("exerciseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let details = fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TrainingDetails
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(details.exerciseName)"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Sets: #\(details.setsNumber) Reps: #\(details.repsNumber)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("section and row \(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row) ")
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            let detailsForRow : NSManagedObject = fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TrainingDetails
            moc?.deleteObject(detailsForRow)
            moc?.save(nil)
            exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()
            exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            exerciseTableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    //PICKER VIEW DELEGATE AND DATASOURCE METHODS
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return daysArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
            let trainingDay = daysArray[row]
            return trainingDay.day
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let currentDay = daysArray[row]
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDetails")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "trainingDay = %@", currentDay)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exerciseName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        detailsArray = (moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDetails])!
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()

    }

    // MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
    {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            // Note that for Insert, we insert a row at the __newIndexPath__
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            // Note that for Delete, we delete the row at __indexPath__
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            // Note that for Update, we update the row at __indexPath__
            if let updateIndexPath = indexPath {
                let cell = self.exerciseTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath)
                let details = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath) as? TrainingDetails

                cell!.textLabel!.text = "\(details!.exerciseName)"
                cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Sets: #\(details!.setsNumber) Reps: #\(details!.repsNumber)"
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            // Note that for Move, we delete the row at __indexPath__
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }

            // Note that for Move, we insert a row at the __newIndexPath__
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        }    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        atIndex sectionIndex: Int,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
    {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            self.exerciseTableView.insertSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case .Delete:
            let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            self.exerciseTableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        default:
            ""
        }
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        exerciseTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to delete a row from the tableView, the app crashes. I read something about `numberOfRowInSection` being called inside `commingEditingStyle`. Anyone has any idea?

I tried many different ways of erasing it, but it won't go.

**UPDATE**

Well, I made it like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("section and row \(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row) ")
        if self.fetchedResultsController == nil {
            println("error when trying to delete object from managed object")

        } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            moc?.deleteObject(detailsArray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            detailsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            var error: NSError?
            moc?.save(&error)
        }
    }
```

Now, when I try to delete something it runs ok, but only if it's the first item in the table view. If I try to delete something in the middle of the table view, the app crashes with **fatal error: Array index out of range**

Also, how do I do this in Swift?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    } else {
        // Do stuff
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
            [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                //abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Crash is an array index out of bounds? Show the exception message. Where are you setting the number of sections?

Comment: Don't try deleting anything from the tableView - use a NSFetchedResultsController and the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods to present Code Data records in a UITableView.  All you do is delete the object from Core Data and the UITableView will magically update itself, similarly when you create a new Core Data object it will also magically just appear in the UITableView.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Objective C code converted to Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if self.fetchedResultsController == nil {

}
else {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete {
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext()
        context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath))
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            NSLog("Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo())
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is [Link](http://objectivec2swift.net/#/converter) to convert Objective C code to Swift

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment above here is an example of a UITableView that uses a NSFetchedResultsController.

The code below includes code to add and delete Core Data objects such that the UITableView will automatically update itself to show/remove the relevant objects.

You can download the full sample app here http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

```
//
//  MasterViewController.m
//  CoreDataLibraryApp
//
//

#import "CompanyViewController.h"
#import "OSCDStackManager.h"
#import "CompanyDetailViewController.h"

@interface CompanyViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation CompanyViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
     self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    //self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(storeChanged) name:OSStoreChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshUI) name:OSDataUpdatedNotification
                                               object:nil];

    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Load"];

    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh)

      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.managedObjectContext = [[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
    FLOG(@"managedObjectContext is %@",self.managedObjectContext);
    [self fetchedResultsController];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = nil;
}
- (void)stopRefresh {

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
- (void)refresh {
    FLOG(@"refresh called");
    [[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] loadDataInBackground];
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopRefresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
-(void)storeChanged {
    FLOG(@"storeChanged called");
    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    self.managedObjectContext = [[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
    FLOG(@"managedObjectContext is %@",self.managedObjectContext);
    [self fetchedResultsController];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = nil;
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
-(void)refreshUI {
    FLOG(@"refreshUI called");

    /*
     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
     // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
     // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     //abort();
     }
     */
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *str = ([[OSCDStackManager sharedManager] isCloudEnabled] ? @"New Company(c)" : @"New Company");
    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:str forKey:@"name"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        //abort();
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table View

// if fetchedResultsController == nil it means the database has not been initialised yet
// and so we just return a single row saying "Loading, please wait..."

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // return 1 section of fetechedResultsController == nil
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil)
        return 1;
    else
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {

        return 1;

    } else {

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {

        return NO;

    } else {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    } else {
        // Do stuff
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
            [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                //abort();
            }
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Don't allow user to select a row if Core Data stack is not set up yet.
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        NSLog(@"  fetchedResultsController == nil");
        return nil;
    }
    // By default, allow row to be selected
    return indexPath;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FLOG(@" called");

    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        FLOG(@"  fetchedResultsController == nil");

    } else {
        FLOG(@"  fetchedResultsController != nil");

            CompanyViewController *newTableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompanyMenuTableViewController"];
            newTableViewController.detailItem = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:newTableViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FLOG(@" called");

    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        FLOG(@"  fetchedResultsController == nil");

    } else {
        FLOG(@"  fetchedResultsController != nil");
       // if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {


            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

                // Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
                self.detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompanyDetailViewController"];
                NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
                //self.detailViewController.title = [object valueForKey:@"name"];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
            } else {
                // We want to highlight the selected row
                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

                FLOG(@" Device is iPad");
                DetailViewManager *detailViewManager = (DetailViewManager*)self.splitViewController.delegate;
                FLOG(@" detailViewManager is %@", detailViewManager);

                // Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
                self.detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompanyDetailViewController"];
                NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
                //self.detailViewController.title = [object valueForKey:@"name"];

                detailViewManager.detailViewController = self.detailViewController;
            }
       // }
    }
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showCompanyDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) return nil;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"controllerWillChangeContent called");
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"controllerDidChangeContent called");
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
 // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 */

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading please wait...";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UIActivityIndicatorView *progressView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        cell.accessoryView = progressView;
        [progressView startAnimating];

    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"name"] description];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
}

@end
```